# How to write automated tests for app in Android managed Work Profile? Cannot access app (Shell does not have permission to access user 10)

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, microsoft-dynamics

Need to write automated tests for a Microsoft app (Dynamic 365 for mobile) as regression tests for custom functionality. The app is installed in a managed work profile in Android (this is mandatory as part of policy settings - I cannot install elsewhere and still use it).

The app would be automated with Appium or Katalon Studio but I cannot start it... the blocker is that I can't get the application ID or see the installed app. I can see my work profile ref but none of the apps within eg:
"adb shell pm list users" gives:

```
UserInfo{0:Owner:c13} running
UserInfo{10:Work profile:1030} running
```

If I try to list contents eg "adb shell pm list packages --user 10" I just get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 10
```

I would be interested in getting other telemetry from the phone but seems like this is locked down for work profile. I also tried "adb root" and got the message:

```
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```